# Linker error with boost::program_options and C++11 on OSX

Tags: c++, macos, boost, clang, xcode4.5

I built boost thusly:

```
~/Downloads/boost_1_52_0
$ sudo ./b2 --build-dir=build --layout=system -j4 toolset=clang variant=release link=shared runtime-link=shared threading=multi cxxflags="-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++" linkflags="-stdlib=libc++" --without-mpi --without-python install
```

and then tried to compile the first example program

```
~/Downloads/boost_1_52_0
$ cd libs/program_options/example                                                                                                                             [18:35:25]

~/Downloads/boost_1_52_0/libs/program_options/example
$ c++ -v -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -lboost_program_options -o first first.cpp                                                                                 [18:38:32]
Apple clang version 4.1 (tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2
Thread model: posix
 "/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.7.0 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name first.cpp -pic-level 1 -mdisable-fp-elim -relaxed-aliasing -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu core2 -target-linker-version 134.9 -v -resource-dir /usr/bin/../lib/clang/4.1 -fmodule-cache-path /var/folders/sq/nfthwlb93k5bl9qyrjbvfylm0000gn/T/clang-module-cache -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/lexi/Downloads/boost_1_52_0/libs/program_options/example -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 169 -stack-protector 1 -mstackrealign -fblocks -fobjc-runtime-has-arc -fobjc-runtime-has-weak -fobjc-dispatch-method=mixed -fobjc-default-synthesize-properties -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o /var/folders/sq/nfthwlb93k5bl9qyrjbvfylm0000gn/T/first-oIjAae.o -x c++ first.cpp
clang -cc1 version 4.1 based upon LLVM 3.1svn default target x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/v1"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/bin/../lib/clang/4.1/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
 "/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.7.0 -o first -lcrt1.10.6.o -lboost_program_options /var/folders/sq/nfthwlb93k5bl9qyrjbvfylm0000gn/T/first-oIjAae.o -lc++ -lSystem /usr/bin/../lib/clang/4.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::program_options::validation_error::validation_error(boost::program_options::validation_error::kind_t, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const& boost::program_options::validators::get_single_string<char>(std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > const&, bool) in first-oIjAae.o
  "boost::program_options::validation_error::what() const", referenced from:
      vtable for boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::program_options::invalid_option_value> in first-oIjAae.o
      vtable for boost::program_options::invalid_option_value in first-oIjAae.o
      vtable for boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::program_options::invalid_option_value> > in first-oIjAae.o
      vtable for boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::program_options::validation_error> in first-oIjAae.o
      vtable for boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::program_options::validation_error> > in first-oIjAae.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What am I doing wrong? The only similar error I could find was [Linker error with Boost & C++ on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11979123/823542) but he is using CMake, gcc and c++03 and his solution of "I recompiled Boost and it worked" isn't particularly helpful.

It's also definitely not the code's fault, since bjam can build the example, but I don't understand enough compiler-fu to be able to look at the output and go "oh so that's how you do it!"

```
~/Downloads/boost_1_52_0/libs/program_options/example
$ ../../../b2 -ad+2 toolset=clang cxxflags="-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++" linkflags="-stdlib=libc++" first
clang-darwin.compile.c++ ../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/example/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/first.o

    "clang++" -x c++ -O0 -g -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -O0 -fno-inline -Wall -g -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -I"../../.." -c -o "../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/example/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/first.o" "first.cpp"

clang-darwin.compile.c++ ../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/cmdline.o

    "clang++" -x c++ -O0 -g -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -O0 -fno-inline -Wall -g -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -I"../../.." -c -o "../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/cmdline.o" "../../../libs/program_options/src/cmdline.cpp"

clang-darwin.compile.c++ ../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/config_file.o

    "clang++" -x c++ -O0 -g -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -O0 -fno-inline -Wall -g -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -I"../../.." -c -o "../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/config_file.o" "../../../libs/program_options/src/config_file.cpp"

clang-darwin.compile.c++ ../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/options_description.o

    "clang++" -x c++ -O0 -g -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -O0 -fno-inline -Wall -g -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -I"../../.." -c -o "../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/options_description.o" "../../../libs/program_options/src/options_description.cpp"

clang-darwin.compile.c++ ../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/parsers.o

    "clang++" -x c++ -O0 -g -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -O0 -fno-inline -Wall -g -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -I"../../.." -c -o "../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/parsers.o" "../../../libs/program_options/src/parsers.cpp"

clang-darwin.compile.c++ ../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/variables_map.o

    "clang++" -x c++ -O0 -g -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -O0 -fno-inline -Wall -g -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -I"../../.." -c -o "../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/variables_map.o" "../../../libs/program_options/src/variables_map.cpp"

clang-darwin.compile.c++ ../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/value_semantic.o

    "clang++" -x c++ -O0 -g -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -O0 -fno-inline -Wall -g -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -I"../../.." -c -o "../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/value_semantic.o" "../../../libs/program_options/src/value_semantic.cpp"

clang-darwin.compile.c++ ../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/positional_options.o

    "clang++" -x c++ -O0 -g -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -O0 -fno-inline -Wall -g -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -I"../../.." -c -o "../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/positional_options.o" "../../../libs/program_options/src/positional_options.cpp"

clang-darwin.compile.c++ ../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/utf8_codecvt_facet.o

    "clang++" -x c++ -O0 -g -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -O0 -fno-inline -Wall -g -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -I"../../.." -c -o "../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/utf8_codecvt_facet.o" "../../../libs/program_options/src/utf8_codecvt_facet.cpp"

In file included from ../../../libs/program_options/src/utf8_codecvt_facet.cpp:15:
In file included from ../../../boost/detail/utf8_codecvt_facet.ipp:13:
../../../boost/detail/utf8_codecvt_facet.hpp:171:17: warning: 'boost::program_options::detail::utf8_codecvt_facet::do_length' hides overloaded virtual function [-Woverloaded-virtual]
    virtual int do_length(
                ^
/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__locale:920:17: note: hidden overloaded virtual function 'std::__1::codecvt<wchar_t, char, __mbstate_t>::do_length' declared here
    virtual int do_length(state_type&, const extern_type* __frm, const extern_type* __end, size_t __mx) const;
                ^
1 warning generated.
clang-darwin.compile.c++ ../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/convert.o

    "clang++" -x c++ -O0 -g -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -O0 -fno-inline -Wall -g -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -I"../../.." -c -o "../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/convert.o" "../../../libs/program_options/src/convert.cpp"

In file included from ../../../libs/program_options/src/convert.cpp:19:
In file included from ../../../boost/program_options/detail/utf8_codecvt_facet.hpp:19:
../../../boost/detail/utf8_codecvt_facet.hpp:171:17: warning: 'boost::program_options::detail::utf8_codecvt_facet::do_length' hides overloaded virtual function [-Woverloaded-virtual]
    virtual int do_length(
                ^
/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__locale:920:17: note: hidden overloaded virtual function 'std::__1::codecvt<wchar_t, char, __mbstate_t>::do_length' declared here
    virtual int do_length(state_type&, const extern_type* __frm, const extern_type* __end, size_t __mx) const;
                ^
1 warning generated.
clang-darwin.compile.c++ ../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/winmain.o

    "clang++" -x c++ -O0 -g -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -O0 -fno-inline -Wall -g -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -I"../../.." -c -o "../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/winmain.o" "../../../libs/program_options/src/winmain.cpp"

clang-darwin.compile.c++ ../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/split.o

    "clang++" -x c++ -O0 -g -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -O0 -fno-inline -Wall -g -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -I"../../.." -c -o "../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/split.o" "../../../libs/program_options/src/split.cpp"

RmTemps ../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/libboost_program_options.a(clean)

    rm -f "../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/libboost_program_options.a" 

clang-darwin.archive ../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/libboost_program_options.a

  "ar"  rc "../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/libboost_program_options.a" "../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/cmdline.o" "../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/config_file.o" "../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/options_description.o" "../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/parsers.o" "../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/variables_map.o" "../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/value_semantic.o" "../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/positional_options.o" "../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/utf8_codecvt_facet.o" "../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/convert.o" "../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/winmain.o" "../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/split.o"
  "ranlib" -cs "../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/libboost_program_options.a"

clang-darwin.link ../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/example/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/first

    "clang++" -stdlib=libc++ -stdlib=libc++  -o "../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/example/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/first" "../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/example/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/first.o" "../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/libboost_program_options.a"    -g


~/Downloads/boost_1_52_0/libs/program_options/example
$ ../../../bin.v2/libs/program_options/example/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/first
Compression level was not set.
```

Comment: Are there any reasons to build boost yourself? If not, just install it from homebrew and be happy. Edit: Oops, didn't notice that this is a year old, though I think it's still valid question.

Comment: @bamboon I needed it to be linked to libc++ in clang's c++11 so I could link it to my clang/libc++/c++11 program. As it is, I never solved this issue and then my macbook exploded (two days out of warranty!) On the bright side, it works fine on Linux now.

Answer (score 2):

First you need the [libc++abi](http://libcxxabi.llvm.org/).

Second you have to add `-nodefaultlibs -lc++ -lc++abi -lm -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc` or `-lc++abi` to your linker command. For one file it should look like this:

```
`clang++ -stdlib=libc++ helloworld.cpp -nodefaultlibs -lc++ -lc++abi -lm -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc`
```

Or this:

```
`clang++ -stdlib=libc++ helloworld.cpp -lc++abi`
```

More info on the official page of [libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org/)

Comment: ld: library not found for -lsupc++

Comment: I did some googling and most of the results I found seemed to suggest that OSX doesn't come with (or need?) that library.

Comment: Can you build that library?

Comment: Apologies, I have been very busy lately. I did some looking and found that libsupc++ is part of g++/libstdc++ and I am using clang/libc++. I'm pretty sure attempting to mix standard libraries is not the solution here, especially since the working example does not do this.